# How to combine the datas of individual apps on google analytics?

Tags: android, mobile, google-analytics, report

I have several apps tracked on Google Analytics, around 50 apps split into 2 accounts.
I get all the datas I need for each app (tracking specific events for instance), but it seems like there is no way to elaborate a report to consolidate them in one single report.

1. Is there a way to elaborate this report that I didn't find ?
2. Is there any common tracking code I could ask our developers team to set within each app, to be able to get all the datas in one view on google analytics ?

Thanks !

Comment: Combining the data for all the 50 apps is not the best thing, the reports would be biased.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way from within the interface to generate reports that span multiple properties or accounts.

However you can use either the API via a 'proper' programming language or pull data from multiple properties and accounts into a google spreadsheet using [Google Apps script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/).

Google [provides a ready made spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/google-analytics-spreadsheet-add-on), which alas has several shortcomings compared to a homebuild solution, namely that it does not auto-update and does support trigger to update data automatically.

Once you have imported your data (which will go into several worksheets) you can use all the usual spreadsheet functions to combine data (and do statistics, produce graphs etc).

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot for your answer. I am considering a second option, I would maintain the two accounts and the individual tracking per app. And then, would it be possible to create a third account with a cluster of apps ? I would use 5 new ID's; and each ID would be associate to a batch of apps. Is it possible to associate two tracking ID's for the same apps ?